# Direct Download By uTorrent

Tags: utorrent, download-manager, peer-to-peer

Instead of using flashget , internet download manager or any other download manager program

Is that possible that i can download any file other than torrent files by utorrent ?

Comment: I wish it could. One download tool could handle all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. µTorrent is a software only specialized in handling torrent files. Flashget can handle torrents so if you want everything in one place, you can use that.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_download_managers#Protocol_support to find a tool that can handle all your protocol needs.